# Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused

Tags: java, maven

I do want to use maven at home for my project, but I can't connect to central repository.

I saw some people suggesting using proxy, but what proxy should I use? How do I determine it? I am very confused about this.

If someone could explain what I need to do step by step I would be very grateful.

---

#### Edit

This turned out to be a firewall issue.

Comment: Are you having this problem from inside a maven build?  If you have access to the internet, in general, then you should not need to proxy the central repository.  Perhaps you could post the POM for your project.

Comment: I've recently installed maven at home and I am trying to create mave project using command: mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-webapp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp

Comment: Are you using maven 3.0.4?  I ran this command with maven 3.0.3 without issue.  The generated project also worked without issue.  Perhaps you should traceroute repo.maven.apache.org to see what the network is doing.

Comment: Have you tried to access the given url via your Web-Browser ?

Comment: if you could explain what is your problem, step by step, I think other people would be grateful.

Comment: sorry guys, im dumb, firewall was blocking me

Comment: Hey, it happens! I'm editing your question so that no one has to read this thread again if they are having a non-firewall issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Manually Overriding the Built-in Repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Repository#MavenRepository-ResolvingArtifactsthroughArtifactory). Or add to your pom (the same for pluginRepository):

```
<repository>              
          <id>central</id>
          <name>Central</name>
          <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: That URL is now invalid. Also, I'm not sure this question makes sense together with the OP's specific issue; but it also doesn't answer the problem more generally, without more explanation. (To wit, I have no idea what you're getting at.)